# Problems After iOS 8 upgrade on iPhone 5s

Tags: iphone, ios

i have iphone5s just bought it a week back and upgraded to iOS 8 and it started restarting at regular intervals and also gets heated up like crazy please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Which version of iOS 8 are you currently running? The lasted update, iOS 8.0.2, fixes some bugs that were introduced in iOS 8.0.1 for some folks. Go to Settings > General > Software Update and make sure you are running the latest iOS version.

Answer (score 0):

Try a hard reset by holding down the <kbd>Home</kbd> and the <kbd>sleep</kbd> together for 15 seconds. The iPhone should then reboot.